# Building a multi dimentional array with a variable consisting of an appended string

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is an example of my original code which seems to work:

```
$MainArray =  array('Part1'=>array(Foo, 4, 2, Cat), 'Part2'=>array(Bar, 3, 1, Dog));
print_r ($MainArray);
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [Part1] => Array ( [0] => Foo [1] => 4 [2] => 2 [3] => Cat ) [Part2] => Array ( [0] => Bar [1] => 3 [2] => 1 [3] => Dog ) )
```

What I would like to do is something like this (the pieces are included based on if statements):

```
$ArrayPieces.="'Part1'=>array(Foo, 4, 2, Cat), ";
$ArrayPieces.="'Part2'=>array(Bar, 3, 1, Dog)";
$MainArray =  array($ArrayPieces);
print_r ($MainArray);
```

But this returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 'Part1'=>array(Foo, 4, 2, Cat), 'Part2'=>array(Bar, 3, 1, Dog))
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this (as you want) is to use `eval()`:

```
<?php

$MainArray =  array('Part1'=>array('Foo', 4, 2, 'Cat'), 'Part2'=>array('Ba$
print_r ($MainArray);

$ArrayPieces = "return array(";
$ArrayPieces .= "'Part1'=>array('Foo', 4, 2, 'Cat'), ";
$ArrayPieces .= "'Part2'=>array('Bar', 3, 1, 'Dog')";
$ArrayPieces .= ");";

$MainArray =  eval($ArrayPieces);

print_r ($MainArray);

?>
```

As for why there is a return in the array string, this is because **`eval` only accepts statements, not expressions.**

The above code will give you what you want:

```
Array
(
    [Part1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Foo
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 2
            [3] => Cat
        )

    [Part2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bar
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
            [3] => Dog
        )

)
```

**However, this is *generally* not recommended. At all! It is very unsafe, (especially when evaluating user input - which you should avoid doing under most, if not ALL circumstances) and in certain situations, it is more trouble than it's worth.**

For more on this matter, refer to this:

[When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for the extra info on the "evil eval". All my inputs are fixed by me, so I think I'm ok there, but I will consider taking more time to approach from a different direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given that your question is based on a pretend situation, it's hard to know exactly what you're looking for, but I think something like this should achieve what you're after:

```
$MainArry = array();
if (foo)
    $MainArray['Part1'] = array(Foo, 4, 2, Cat);
if (bar)
    $MainArray['Part2'] = array(Bar, 3, 1, Dog);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to deserialize an array.  According to your example, you're looking to construct PHP syntax in a string and then execute it later.

If this is what you absolutely *must do*, look at [the *eval* PHP function](http://php.net/eval)

Personally, I don't like "eval".

Is there an opportunity to use JavaScript Object Notation? If so, express your above example as:

```
$json_pieces = '{';
$json_pieces .= '"Part1": ["Foo", 4, 2, "Cat"],';
$json_pieces .= '"Part2": ["Bar", 3, 1, "Dog"]';
$json_pieces .= '}'
$MainArray = json_decode( $json_pieces, TRUE );
print_r( $main_array );
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative- I'll check into this more.

Comment: Let me know what you decide. I'm also interested to know more about what you're doing and how you arrived at the need to do piecewise code generation.